# Using Pandas to drop the extra rows after satisfying a condition

Tags: pandas

My sample `df` looks like this

```
id   year    success
1    2000      N
1    2001      N
1    2002      Y
1    2003      N
1    2004      N
2    2000      N
2    2001      N
2    2002      N
3    2000      N
3    2001      N
3    2002      Y
....
```

Here, we can see that the `id==1` and `id==3` has both `success==Y` and `success==N` but `id==2` only has `success==N`

**What I want to do?**

- I want to only have `rows` in which if we find the first `success==Y`, we drop the remaining column for that group, eg `id==1`

This is how the new `df` should look.

```
id   year    success
1    2000      N
1    2001      N
1    2002      Y
2    2000      N
2    2001      N
2    2002      N
3    2000      N
3    2001      N
3    2002      Y
....
```

Here, in the above `df` we removed the extra rows after we encountered `success==Y`. Since, `id==2` does not have `success==Y`, we did not remove any rows and in `id==2`, the last row is the `Y` so no rows were removed.

**What I did?**

- I tried to group the `id` but then I want all the results even though I have duplicate ids. So this did not work.

Could someone please help me achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check `success` column against value `Y`, which gives you True value where `success=Y`; To mark all values after first `Y` as drop, we can further use `cummax` on this condition; Finally use the negated condition to filter the data frame:

```
df[~df.success.eq('Y').groupby(df.id).apply(lambda g: g.cummax().shift(fill_value=False))]

    id  year success
0    1  2000       N
1    1  2001       N
2    1  2002       Y
5    2  2000       N
6    2  2001       N
7    2  2002       N
8    3  2000       N
9    3  2001       N
10   3  2002       Y
```

Comment: Thanks for composing the answer. If you get sometime then could you possibly explain your answer? especially the part where it drops the row data?

Comment: Updated with some explanations. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df.loc[(df.index <= df['id'].map(df['success'].eq('Y').groupby(df['id']).idxmax())) | 
df['success'].eq('N').groupby(df['id']).transform('all')])
```

or

```
(df.loc[df.groupby('id')['success']
.transform(lambda x: x.eq('Y')
.cumsum()
.shift()
.fillna(0)
.eq(0))])
```

Output:

```
    id  year success
0    1  2000       N
1    1  2001       N
2    1  2002       Y
5    2  2000       N
6    2  2001       N
7    2  2002       N
8    3  2000       N
9    3  2001       N
10   3  2002       Y
```